# Can this code be further reduce , maybe without variable "k" (in this example)

Tags: java

[Click here for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SQ4t.jpg)

**JAVA**

In this code, I have to use 7 `for` loops and assign the variable `k`. Is there any way to reduce the time complexity of this code, maybe without variable "k"

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class PracticePattern6 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k=1;
        for(int i=0;i<2*n+1;i++)
        {
            if(i<n+1)
            {
                for(int j = i ;j<n;j++)
                { 
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
                for(int j =0;j<2*i+1;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                for(int j = i ;j<n;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
        
            }
            
            else
            {
            
                for(int j=0;j<i-n;j++)
                {
                        System.out.print("* ");
                }
                    for(int j=0;j<2*n-k;j++)
                    {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                    }
                 for(int j=0;j<i-n;j++)
                 {
                        System.out.print("* ");
                 }
                 k+=2;
             }
             System.out.println();
        }
      sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do ? Can you add some input and output ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar i have added the image now.....please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is allowed to use an intermediate array of Strings/chars to build the entire picture before printing it, it can be done in the following way:

1. Create entire field and populate it with required patterns for the left and right halves (using standard `Arrays.fill` method).
2. Set "empty" cells for top and bottom halves of the field, calculating the `left` and `right` position of the empty space.
3. Print the field.

Example:

```java
public static void printRhombPattern(int size, String leftPattern, String rightPattern, String empty) {
    int cols = 2 * size;
    int rows = cols + 1;

    String[][] field = new String[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        field[i] = new String[cols];
        Arrays.fill(field[i], 0, size, leftPattern);
        Arrays.fill(field[i], size, cols, rightPattern);
    }
        
    int left = cols / 2 - 1;
    // starting from i == 1 to skip the first and the last rows
    for (int i = 1, right = left + 1; i <= size; i++, left--, right++) {
            
        for (int j = left; j <= right; j++) {
            field[i][j] = empty;             // clean cells in the top half
            field[rows - 1 - i][j] = empty;  // clean cells in the bottom half
        }
    }

    // main printing
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print(field[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printRhombPattern(5, "* ", " *", "  ");
}
```

Output:

```
* * * * *  * * * * *
* * * *      * * * *
* * *          * * *
* *              * *
*                  *
                    
*                  *
* *              * *
* * *          * * *
* * * *      * * * *
* * * * *  * * * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a little simpler, however I did not do a side by side check to make sure they have the exact same output, if they do not the outputs are very similar and with a little tweaking you could make this code work for the exact correct output I believe.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<n-i;j++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        for(int j = 0;j<i*2;j++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for(int j = 0;j<n-i;j++) {
            System.out.print(" *");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i = n;i>=0;i--) {
        for(int j = n;j>i;j--) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        for(int j = n;j>n-i*2;j--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for(int j = n;j>i;j--) {
            System.out.print(" *");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

If you talk about the time complexity, the big-O of the specified code for printing the diamond whitespace.

```
 https://ideone.com/foelhX
```

The current solution is O(N^2) which is minimal to print 2-D shape.
moreover, you can reduce some constants, that would not impact your time complexity.

In case you are starting programming, this would be a helpful resource:

```
https://github.com/joney000/Java-Competitive-Programming
```